# Authenticate webapp with separate frontend and backend on ADFS

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, web-applications, saml, adfs

I have a web application composed of an Angular frontend and a Java Spring backend.
I need to integrate this application with an Active Directory ADFS.
I have some confusion in mind, but what I think is to register the application inside the AD (to generate client_id and scope), at this point all unauthenticated calls to the frontend would be redirected to the ADFS login page.
The frontend would get an access_token from ADFS, which would be communicated to the backend (as bearer authentication). The backend could thus validate the authentication of the calls by interfacing directly with the ADFS (and obtain information about the logged in user).
In your opinion is this the best implementation or there are better alternatives (SAML, LDAP or whatever)?
Thank you all

I would like to be able to authenticate frontend and backend, so that the backend can verify the logged in user.

[architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH2gm.jpg)